# Android Build project Error : Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm New In Android Studio And I don't know what is this problem
if I delete Room Library It works but with Room Dependency It has bug
And I Delete Build and .gradle Folder From My Project Folder And It Did not matter
Can you Help Me?
[image: Build Error]

My Build.gradle :

Its Room Library Problem??

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mvp_sample_todolist"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary(true)

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    def room_version = "2.3.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your vpn is turn on if vpn is on, change your gradle plugin version

Comment: doesn't change :(

Comment: whats your gradle plugin version?